# Lumia 620 touchscreen calibration

Tags: lumia

My replacement touchscreen is all calibrated funny.. it's an unofficial one off eBay (requiring me to downgrade from Amber.. boo!)

I've fitted screens before without trouble and everything's in alignment so I'm not sure where I might have slipped up.. is there anything I can try?

It seems the screen 'touches' slightly to the left of my finger, so that I can hardly touch the right hand of the screen at all. Also the bottom buttons require you to touch slightly above them to get any response.

Could it perhaps be a duff screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nokia use Windows Phone.
Windows phone has a built-in Touchscreen Calibration feature so it must be auto-calibrated. If not, then your touchscrean may be a cheap chinese fake screen so you have to replace it on a Nokia Care center in order to avoid buying another fake screen.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, No "Diagnostics Tool" menu available for users in windows phone 8. That's the only way I know to test the touch or calibrate it. So you must visit a repair center to make them look at it.

Anyway, as long as you changed the screen yourself, you might be interested in finding and downloading "Nokia Care Suite" so you can run the diagnostics tools and fix this.

Comment: Thank you - I have the care suite, and can run some diagnostics (which tell me that everything, including the touchscreen 'works'). Am I missing some function I can use to fix the calibration?

Comment: @TablooQuijico Then I guess it is the cheap screen.

Comment: @TablooQuijico 100%! :)